# Dateoverlap in data.frame in R

Tags: r, date, overlap

I'm trying to make a new variable in my dataframe based on date overlapping.

My `data` looks like this

```
         People   Company  Start      End
1        Person1  CompanyA 2017-04-27 2019-12-31
2        Person2  CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-08-30
3        Person3  CompanyA 2013-04-27 2019-12-31
4        Person4  CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-12-31
5        Person5  CompanyC 2016-05-13 2019-12-31
```

I would like to check if each person was in the company at the following `dates`

```
    2016-12-31
    2017-12-31
    2018-12-31
    2019-12-31
...
```

I'm using the `%overlaps%` from the `DescTools` library. And if I check just one row in my `data`

```
c(data$Start[1], data$End[1]) %overlaps% dates[1]
```

it returns `TRUE` (or `FALSE` in other cases) as I expect. But I would like to know this for each row and save in my variables `data$y2017`, `data$y2018`, `data$y2019` etc. But I have trouble with this.

Because if I just try to do this on every row it doesn't work and just returns `NA` for each row. For example if I try to see who was there in `2016-12-31`:

```
data$y2016 <- c(data$Start, data$End) %overlaps% dates[1]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach

Core of this solution is the `data.table::foverlaps()`-function to check is a Start-End interval in the `DT.dates` data.table is within the Start-End interval in `DT`.

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
DT <- fread("         People   Company  Start      End
        Person1  CompanyA 2017-04-27 2019-12-31
        Person2  CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-08-30
        Person3  CompanyA 2013-04-27 2019-12-31
        Person4  CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-12-31
        Person5  CompanyC 2016-05-13 2019-12-31")
DT[, Start := as.Date(Start)]
DT[, End := as.Date(End)]
DT.dates <- data.table( Start = as.Date(c("2016-12-31","2017-12-31","2018-12-31","2019-12-31")),
                        End   = as.Date(c("2016-12-31","2017-12-31","2018-12-31","2019-12-31")))

# Set keys
setkey(DT, Start, End)
setkey(DT.dates, Start, End)
# Perform overlapjoin and cast to wide
dcast(foverlaps(DT.dates, DT), People + Company + Start + End ~ i.Start, 
      value.var = "i.Start", fun.aggregate = length)
#     People  Company      Start        End 2016-12-31 2017-12-31 2018-12-31 2019-12-31
# 1: Person1 CompanyA 2017-04-27 2019-12-31          0          1          1          1
# 2: Person2 CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-08-30          0          1          1          0
# 3: Person3 CompanyA 2013-04-27 2019-12-31          1          1          1          1
# 4: Person4 CompanyB 2017-04-27 2019-12-31          0          1          1          1
# 5: Person5 CompanyC 2016-05-13 2019-12-31          1          1          1          1
```

Comment: I followed your code but when I run "setkey(DT, Start, End)" it replaces some dates (e.g. 2017-04-27) with NA.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an error on my part. Thanks for your help. It works!